# How to encrypt critical data (for example password) in a phonegap app?

Tags: extjs, encryption, cordova, passwords, touch

I have an important question for mobile app development with sencha touch 2 and phonegap.
I get important datas from server and have to store them on the client.
Therefore I have the choice between localStorage and Web Sql Database.
The real problem is that this data have to be encrypted. After reading lots of sites I came to
the conclusion that phonegap not supports encrytion? Am I right?
That means I have to use an javascript framework to encrypt critical data like passwords...

Or maybe I have access to the encryption option of the mobile device to use it?

What do you think about it? Did somebody had this problem too?

I am looking forward to read how other programmers realize such problems :-)